# Defining weak solutions to infinitely many SDEs on the same probability space

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose I have an SDE of the form
$$dX_t=b(X_t)dt+\sigma (X_t)dB_t+\int_{\mathbb{R}}G_{t-}(y)N(dtdy)$$
which I can solve weakly if I cut off the last integral to range over the set $\{\mid{y}\mid > \epsilon\}$.

In order to construct a full solution I would like to define the sequence of weak solution to the cut-off equations on the same probability space and show that both sides converge (a.s) to the full solution (I can do this with particular coefficients that I have).

My idea was to take a weak solution to each equation, define it on the appropriate path space by taking its distribution as the probability measures, take an infinite product of the resulting spaces and then define the corresponding processes via composition of a canonical process and a projection.

Is something simmilar to this possible?

Comment: I assume that $N$ is a Poisson random measure on $\mathbb{R}_+\times \mathbb{R} $. Then $$ \int_0^t \int_{|y|<\epsilon} G_{s-}(y)N(\,d s \,d y) = \sum_{(s,y)\in (0,t]\times (-\epsilon, \epsilon) } G_{s-}(y) \mathbb{1}(N(\{s\}, \{y\}) \neq 0)$$ is a possibly infinite random sum. Do you know surely that this sum converges in your case?

Comment: Yes. If I had strong solutions it would work out,, so I'm trying to find a way to do it with weak solutions.